# Upgrade Cordova on MFP

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Invoking the navigator.camera.getPicture(...) in a MFP app (Android environment) will cause the app to be temporarily hidden when the callbacks are called. MPF has 7.0 has cordova 3.6.4.

I tried the same thing in cordova 5 (with cordova android 5) app and the app is always visible.

How can I upgrade the cordova within MFP from MFP Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upgrade the Cordova version in MobileFirst Hybrid applications.

What you can do is open a PMR so that the development team will patch the existing Cordova version with the fix for this issue and provide you with an iFix.